# angular custom libraries typing paths are messed up, anything I am doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, ng-packagr

so I've built my first custom angular library (with ng-packagr behind the scenes). Unfortunately my built library contains relative paths to my local machine which obviously won't work for others.

I've created a sample application to test the custom lib.

**mya.animations.ts**

```
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';


export const FLYOUT_ANIMATIONS = trigger('slideContent', [
  state('void', style({transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)', opacity: 0})),
  state('enter_TOP', style({transform: 'none', opacity: 1})),
  state('leave_TOP', style({transform: 'translate3d(0, -25%, 0)', opacity: 0})),
  transition('* => *', animate(ANIMATION_TIMINGS))
]);

export const CARET_ANIMATIONS = trigger('rotateCaret', [
  state('open', style({transform: 'rotate(180deg)'})),
  state('closed', style({transform: 'rotate(0)'})),
  transition('* => *', animate(ANIMATION_TIMINGS))
]);
```

So while building there's a file called **mya.animations.d.ts** being generated. Unfortunately these paths can't be resolved by anyone else.

```
export declare const EXPAND_COLLAPSE_ANIMATIONS: import("../../../../../../../../../../Users/mya/Development/mya-angular-libraries/node_modules/@angular/animations/src/animation_metadata").AnimationTriggerMetadata;

export declare const CARET_ANIMATIONS: import("../../../../../../../../../../Users/mya/Development/mya-angular-libraries/node_modules/@angular/animations/src/animation_metadata").AnimationTriggerMetadata;
```

In my component I just then import these animations via

```
@Component({
...
animations: [CARET_ANIMATIONS]
...
})
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show your ng-packagr.json?

Comment: Thats my ng-package.json   ```{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/pidx-footer",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public_api.ts"
  }
}   ```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using this paths? Just paste the snippet where you are using.

This generally happens when you are using variable defined outside of the constructor.

Comment: So in my *mya.animations.ts* I declare the animations trigger and export them. In my component I import it and add it to the component decorator like shown in the question above.

Comment: I need the code where you are imprting this animation file and and place where you are using. I faced this problem in my lib too for some other code

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sure. Hopefully this is what you want to know => In my component I import the animation ```import {CARET_ANIMATIONS} from './mya.animations';``` And then add it to an HTMLElement via ```<span class="icon icon--arrow-down-thin navigation-footer__icon" [@rotateCaret]="navigationSection.animationState"></span>``` I then set the animationState for the the navigationSection in the compontent e.g. ```navgationSections[0].animationState = 'closed'```I dont't use CARET_ANIMATIONS anywhere else in my code.

Comment: `navigationSection` declaration and definition, I want to see in the file where you have imported `import {CARET_ANIMATIONS} from './mya.animations';`

Comment: If I just inline those animations and not assign them to a const first, there's nothing being added to the .d.ts file. Probably cause the decorators are handled in the metadata file

Comment: In my case, The error was because

`export class SomeComponent {
    a = someImport;
    b= new SomeOtherThing(someImport);

  constructor() {
{
}`

since the definition was outside of `constructor` things were messed up.

Comment: OKay thanks. I've got the feeling that this has to to with the decorator and it's transpiling or rather resolution of the metadata